# Your app did not achieve the core functionality described in your marketing materials

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I am facing a problem while uploading new version of the application.

I have checked the answer of [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791842/2-3-apps-that-do-not-perform-as-advertised-by-the-developer-will-be-rejected) but didn't find the satisfied answer.

**Issue:**

> > Your app has the UIFileSharingEnabled key set to true in the Info.plist, but this feature is not functional.
>
> When file sharing is enabled, the entire Documents folder is used for
>   file sharing. Files that are not intended for user access via the file
>   sharing feature should be stored in another part of your application's
>   bundle. If your application does not require the file sharing feature,
>   the UIFileSharingEnabled key in the Info.plist should not be set to
>   true.

In Info Plist i have set the `Application supports iTunes file  sharing` to Yes.

For all the Document operation i have used below code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Should the files you store in the Documents folder be accessed by the user via iTunes?

Comment: yes its accessed by the user. user can do only save a file from Documents folder

Comment: Are there files in the Documents folder that the user shouldn't be able to access (or delete or rename) via iTunes?

Comment: yes there is file that is not in use for the user only for the programming purpose..so there will be problem?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. The user will be able to delete or renamed any file in the Documents folder due to file sharing being enabled. Do exactly what Apple told you. Store the file elsewhere or turn off sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions has already been answered here:

[Where we have to store download data in iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963484/where-we-have-to-store-download-data-in-iphone-application)

Most of us use the Documents folder for storing app data, but since you give the user access to that folder, you should use another folder.

That folder is clearly Library and inside that one, you should choose either Cache or Application Support: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4

Finally, you should remember not to upload those data to iCloud unless necessary. That is explained in the last link I supplied.